# Simple probability question about coins

Tags: combinatorics

What is the probability of getting exactly 5 heads in 10 tosses of a coin?

The answer is $$\frac{\binom{10}{5}}{2^5}$$

Comment: I believe it's $$\frac{\binom{10}5}{2^{10}}.$$ But what's your question?

Comment: How did the author get this?

Comment: Does the author say that the denominator is $2^5$, or $2^{10}$?

Comment: It's exercise 1.7 of Ian Anderson, A first course in discrete mathematics.

Comment: @MJD   It's $2^5$

Comment: That's an error, then.  Does my answer above make more sense, or would you like someone explain it in more detail?

Comment: @MJD $\frac{\binom{10}{5}}{2^{10}}$ was my first answer but when I saw the solution in the book, I was surprised.

Comment: That will be in a strange universe with probabilities > 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked to make sure you understood the question correctly: (you did.)

[image: snapshot of exercise]

As we discussed in the comments, the solution given on page 183 is erroneous:

[image: snapshot of erroneous solution]

1. There are $$\binom{10}5$$ ways to select five of ten coins to have heads.
2. There are $2^{10}$ ways that the coins can fall.

Therefore the answer,  as you surmised, is $$\frac{\binom{10}5}{2^{10}} = \frac{252}{1024}\approx 0.246.$$

The answer clearly can't be ${\binom{10}5/ 2^5 }= 7.875$, since this is larger than 1. I have sent an error report to the author.

[Addendum 2013-08-23: The author has not replied to my erratum.]

Answer (score 1):

This is the binomial distribution with $p = (1-p) = \frac{1}{2}, n=10, k=5$ so the answer is
$$
{n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}\\
= {10 \choose 5} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^5 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^5\\
= \frac{10 \choose 5}{2^{10}}
$$